# how can i use a function inside main package from a file in another package in GO?

Tags: go

Hi I want to call a method inside the main package, my project struct is like this: 
src:

- go files : package main
- Postgres folder:

  - go files: postgres package

now I want to call a method inside main package from the go files inside the postgres folder that is from postgres package. 
I tried to import "foo/src"
then using src.Myfunction but I got an error:

```
import "foo/src" is a program, not an importable package
```

Comment: You can't import a main package. You need to refactor the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `main` is supposed to be used only to implement the binary/command specific code. It usually imports code from other packages to glue everything together. If you need to import something *from* the package `main`, that code is probably not specific to that command, so it should belong to another package. After you refactor the code, you can import it from the package `main` and from your other package which also requires it.